# Why is $C^\infty$ a subspace of its dual?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Actually, let me start with understanding the argument for $S(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset S'(\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $S$ is Schwartz and $S'$ is the space of tempered
distributions. That is, we can identify any $\Psi \in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$, with a 
 $u \in S'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ defined to be 
$u\phi = \int \Psi \phi$, $\phi \in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$. All I know is from the density of
$S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, there exists
a sequence $\phi_n \in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\int \phi_n \Psi \to 
\int |\Psi|^2$. How do I go from here?

I imagine the answer to my original question will also be along the same lines? thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question already? We can identify any $\Psi \in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $u \in S^{\prime}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. In other words, there is an embedding (as sets) $S(\mathbb{R}^n) \hookrightarrow S^{\prime}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. This is the only way to understand the notation $S(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset S^{\prime}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ which makes sense to me.

Comment: Oops, I am sorry I don't understand then! Why does what I have written mean that there is some $\phi \in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\Psi (x) = u\phi$, or is that not what is meant by "identifying" with a $\Psi$ with a $u$?

Comment: Identifying here means that for each $\phi \in S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the map $\phi^* : S(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\phi^*(u) = \int \phi u$ is a continuous linear functional on $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (prove it!) and, thus, lies in $S^{\prime}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Therefore, we can define a map $* : S(\mathbb{R}^n) \to S^{\prime}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ which maps each function $\phi$ to the functional $\phi^*$. This map is a bijection so we can say that space of Schwartz functions is "contained" in the space of tempered distributions.

Comment: As @ПетяНарышкин mentioned, here the inclusion must be understood as an embedding. We are interpreting a smooth function in two different ways.

Comment: Thanks @ПетяНарышкин! That answers my question. But, just to clarify, in your comment, the map $*$ is not a bijection, isn't that the point? It's only an injection, am I correct?

Comment: Thank you @Behnam! Could you see my comment above?

Comment: No problem, @rivendell ;) And yes, you're right, this map is only an injection.

Comment: It is not obvious that $\mathbb C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ imbeds naturally into its dual, in contrast to the case of Schwartz functions naturally imbedding into their dual by the "integrate against" map.

Answer (score 2):

The space $C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ does not *naturally* imbed into its dual which is the space of distributions with compact support -- the reason is that for $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ the attempted map $\psi_f(g)=\int f(x)g(x)dx$ is not well defined (e.g., for $f=g=1$). It is well-defined for $f\in\mathscr D(\mathbb R^n)$, the space of smooth functions with compact support, and a precise meaning of *natural* could be that $\mathscr D(\mathbb R)\to C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)'$, $f\mapsto \psi_f$ does not have a continuous extension to a map $C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)\to C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)'$.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to remark that, in the complex setting at least, there is actually an interesting embedding in the opposite direction, $\mathscr F \colon(C^\infty (\mathbb R^n))’\to C^\infty (\mathbb R^n) $ given by the Fourier transform. In fact, every compactly supported distribution is a tempered distribution (i.e., $(C^\infty(\mathbb R^n))’\hookrightarrow \mathscr S’(\mathbb R^n)$) and, by the Paley Wiener theorem, its Fourier transform is smooth. This also means that, given two compactly distributions $u,v$, it is well-defined the pairing $\langle{u,\mathscr Fv}\rangle$.